# Sticky-top not working with bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to figure out why the sticky-top function is not working. I got around the issue by writing some horrid looking javascript code but was hoping someone might have an idea.
I just want it to stick to the top of the screen as I scroll over some other element on the page at 50px.

The navbar looks and works as intended (as shown in the picture) but this might be a PEBCAK situation...

```html
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
     
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="secondNav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `fixed-top`  or  `sticky-top`.
Note that sticky-top uses `position: sticky`, which isn’t fully supported in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `navbar-fixed-top` try just `fixed-top`. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, 'fixed-top' does not seem to work/ do anything. 'navbar-fixed-top' keeps the navbar at the top so I guess for now it will have to do